# Check if node exists and its empty in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XSL file where I need to check if XML node **bean:usz-consent** exists and its empty.
I tried many variants and anyone doesnt work for me.

XML:

```
<bean:container>
 <bean:account></bean:account>
 <bean:subscriptions channel="sms" available="false"></bean:subscriptions>
 <bean:subscriptions channel="sms" available="true"></bean:subscriptions>
 <bean:certificates></bean:certificates>
 <bean:in-settlements></bean:in-settlements>
 <bean:usz-consent></bean:usz-consent>
</bean:container>
```

I tried to do something like:

```
<xsl:template match="bean:usz-consent">
  <xsl:if test="bean:usz-consent/text() = ''">
    <summary:show-popup>true</summary:show-popup>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="bean:usz-consent">
  <xsl:if test="string(//bean:usz-consent) = ''">
    <summary:show-popup>true</summary:show-popup>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please add your XML to your question **as code**. Also post your best attempt so we can fix it, instead of having to write your code for you from scratch.

Comment: Also consider to explain in more detail what you consider "empty", i.e. no child elements, no child nodes, only white space contents.

Comment: "empty"  means no child ellements, no child nodes, only **bean:usz-consent** with nothing inside

Comment: Added my XML and XSL

Comment: Instead of `<xsl:if test="bean:usz-consent/text() = ''">` try `<xsl:if test="not(node())">`. There may be a better way, but you're not showing a [mcve]. But clearly your test is in the wrong context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use

```
<xsl:template match="bean:usz-consent[not(node())]">
    <summary:show-popup>true</summary:show-popup>
</xsl:template>
```

then the template matches only `bean:usz-consent` which have no child nodes at all (no child elements nor text nor comments nor processing instructions).